# Sentiment analysis for Dutch tweets using NLTK Corpus conll2002

Tags: python, twitter, nltk, sentiment-analysis, corpus

I need sentiment analysis done for a list of tweets in Dutch language and I am using `conll2002` for the same. Here is the code that I'm using :

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import conll2002
import time

t=time.time()

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

#negids = conll2002.fileids('neg')
def train():
    #negids = conll2002.fileids('neg')
    #posids = conll2002.fileids('pos')
    negids = conll2002.fileids()
    posids = conll2002.fileids()

    negfeats = [(word_feats(conll2002.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
    posfeats = [(word_feats(conll2002.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

    negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4
    poscutoff = len(posfeats)*3/4

    trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]
    testfeats = negfeats[negcutoff:] + posfeats[poscutoff:]
    print 'train on %d instances, test on %d instances' % (len(trainfeats), len(testfeats))

    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
    print 'accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testfeats)
    classifier.show_most_informative_features()
x=train()
print x
print time.time()-t
```

The above code works but with the output as following :

```
train on 8 instances, test on 4 instances
accuracy: 0.5
Most Informative Features
                poderlas = True              pos : neg    =      1.0 : 1.0
                   voert = True              pos : neg    =      1.0 : 1.0
            contundencia = True              pos : neg    =      1.0 : 1.0
          encuestocracia = None              pos : neg    =      1.0 : 1.0
                 alivien = None              pos : neg    =      1.0 : 1.0
                  Bogotá = True              pos : neg    =      1.0 : 1.0
          Especialidades = True              pos : neg    =      1.0 : 1.0
         hoofdredacteurs = True              pos : neg    =      1.0 : 1.0
               quisieron = True              pos : neg    =      1.0 : 1.0
               asciendan = None              pos : neg    =      1.0 : 1.0
None
9.21083234
```

The pos:neg ratio comes out to be 1:1 for all cases. How can I fix that? I figured the problem might be in the following statements that I have currently commented out in the code :

```
negids = conll2002.fileids('neg')
posids = conll2002.fileids('pos')
```

The error that I get if I don't comment out the above two statements is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "naive1.py", line 31, in <module>
    x=train()
  File "naive1.py", line 13, in train
    negids = conll2002.fileids('neg')
TypeError: fileids() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I tried using self to fix this problem but it still doesn't work. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fileids()` method accepts a `categories` argument, but in categorized corpora only. For example:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> brown.fileids("mystery")
['cl01', 'cl02', 'cl03', 'cl04', 'cl05', 'cl06', 'cl07', 'cl08', 'cl09', 
'cl10', 'cl11', 'cl12', 'cl13', 'cl14', 'cl15', 'cl16', 'cl17', 'cl18', 
'cl19', 'cl20', 'cl21', 'cl22', 'cl23', 'cl24']
```

Your calls are failing because the CONLL corpora do not have categories. And this is because they are not annotated for sentiment: both CONLL 2000 and CONLL 2002 are chunked corpora (NP/PP and named entities respectively).

```
>>> conll2002.categories()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ConllChunkCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'categories'
```

So the short answer to your question is, you can't train a sentiment analyzer on the conll2002 corpus.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Can you suggest some other way to do sentiment analysis for tweets in Dutch language? Should I try Neural Network for the same by having a list of positive tweets and negative tweets classified as 'good' and 'bad' and then train the model based on that? Please suggest an alternative.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you have a sentiment corpus for Dutch (as you seem to be saying), you can just use it to train a `NaiveBayesClassifier` as shown in the book. If you don't have a sentiment corpus, how is a different _supervised_ algorithm going to help you?

Comment: Right now I have a list of 500 textual statements in dutch and their corresponding scores based on their sentiments. For example, a positive tweet has a %age around 90 and a negative tweet has a %age around 50. Can I use this as the training data set for my Artificial Neural Network model and train it to predict the sentiment score for other tweets? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Try it and see which classifier gives you better performance.